# How to seperate the one modules function across multiple .R files?

Tags: r, r-box

to organize the functions in my largest r-project, I am trying to migrate from a horribly flat folder structure to a nicely modularized hierarchical one using the box package. How can I keep on R-file per function in nested modules?

```
 R  
 |- ...  
 |- preproc  
 |     |- acti
...   ... |- __init__.R   <- How to export functions across all files   
          |- funA.R       <- stores funA()      
          |- funB.R       <- stores funB()  
          |- ...
```

After `box::use(./R/preproc/acti)` I would like to access all seperately stored functions via
acti$funA()
acti$funB()
etc.

Many thanks!

In `__init__.R`, I tried

```
#' export
box:use(.)
```

which gives no access to the functions.
And

```
#' export
box:use(./funA,./funB)
```

which gives overly nested calls: `acti$funA$funA()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

‘box’ enforces “one file” = “one module”.

However, you can create a module which reexports the functions of its submodules (or anything else it imports). Your code already does that, but you are reexporting the *modules themselves*, not their exported names. — To export the names from inside the module, attach them inside `preproc/acti/__init__.r`:

```
#' @export
box::use(
  ./funA[...],
  ./funB[...],
)
```

Now you can use them directly:

```
box::use(./preproc/acti)

ls(acti)
# [1] "funA" "funB"

acti$funA()
# [1] "A"
```

Comment: Many thanks Konrad! What a nice flexibility when it comes to nesting.