# Load all functions in one go using r box package

Tags: r, r-box

I am using the box package. In my project, I have a functions folder, with two functions saved in there: hello.r and goodbye.r

I can load them using the box package using:

```
box::use(functions/hello)
box::use(functions/goodbye)
```

The problem is that I potentially have dozens of .r files in the functions folder (one .r file for each function).

Is there a way of loading all the .r files in one go (whilst still using the box package) without having to repeat the box::use function many times?

Comment: Is wrapping the functions in a package an option?

Comment: normally it would be but in this instance I need to use the box package

Comment: See also: [How to seperate the one modules function across multiple .R files?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76980673/1968)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `box::use` uses Non-Standard Evaluation (NSE) you have to transform strings into unevaluated language objects:

```r
rm(list = ls())
ls()
# character(0)

rex <- "\\.[rR]$"
fld <- "functions"

fs::dir_tree(fld)
# functions
# ├── goodbye.R
# └── hello.R

fns <- list.files(fld, rex) |>     ## read all files in the folder
  gsub(rex, "", x = _) |>          ## drop extension
  paste(fld, . = _, sep = "/") |>  ## pre-pend folder
  lapply(str2lang)                 ## transform string into language object

## or (`tools` is a base package)
# fns <- tools::list_files_with_exts(fld, "R") |> 
#   tools::file_path_sans_ext() |>
#   lapply(str2lang)

## call box::use with the the newly creataed list
do.call(box::use, fns)
ls()
# [1] "fld"     "fns"     "goodbye" "hello"   "rex"
```

---

*Update based on Friede's tip to use `str2lang`*

Comment: Nice edit to base R (+1). `str2lang(.x)` might be less verbose.

Comment: Was not aware of this function (one should read help files even of known functions such as `parse`). Adapted my code and attributed the change. Thanks for showing me a new function.

Answer (score 4):

For what it’s worth, it’s good practice to list the imports explicitly, rather than doing a catch-all of nested files. This was [a conscious design decision](https://github.com/klmr/box/issues/68#issuecomment-1838584736) of ‘box’, and working around it is generally not recommended.

That said, you don’t have to repeat the `box::use()` call, because `box::use()` supports multiple import declarations:

```r
box::use(
  functions/hello,
  functions/goodbye,
)
```

This is the recommended syntax for multiple imports in the same scope.

Furthermore, you can make `functions` itself *into* a module, and make it export all nested submodules. This seems to be appropriate in your case anyway, since the actual user-facing module seems to be `functions`, not each individual file in the folder — the latter should be strictly an implementation detail of the module, the user should not know or care about it.

In that case, add an `__init__.r` file to the `functions` folder with the following code:

```r
#' @export
box::use(
  ./hello,
  ./goodbye,
)
```

Now the user only needs a single import. However, `function` on its own is not a valid module name because module names (intentionally) need to be namespaced (just like GitHub projects need to be namespaced: you can’t just have a GitHub project `box`, it needs to be called (e.g.) `klmr/box`. So let’s say you have your module `basil/functions` (i.e. move the folder `functions` into a parent folder `basil` which is in the module search path), then you can use your module via

```r
box::use(basil/functions[...])
```

The other solutions presented here work, but they are explicitly contravening the spirit of the ‘box’ package, and if you write modules this way you are not taking best advantage of the infrastructure that ‘box’ provides. I would only ever recommend using the other solutions as a quick hack while porting large legacy projects to ‘box’ — never as a long-term solution.

Comment: so just for my own understanding, what aspects of the 'box' infrastructure would I lose by using the quick hacks?

Comment: @Basil You can no longer discover dependencies via static analysis. This isn’t very widely used yet but e.g. ‘renv’ already uses it to discover when packages are imported via `box::use()`. There are plans to make static analysis of ‘box’ modules a lot more widely available in the future. — But the biggest loss in my view is code readability: the code to load dependencies is more convoluted, and does not directly show which names are imported.

Answer (score 3):

**1)** On Windows assume the .R files are all in the `boxtest` folder.  This creates a new file `boxtest.R` in the current folder and then uses `box::use`

```
shell("copy boxtest\\*.R > boxtest.R")
box::use(./boxtest[...])  # or remove [...] to not export objects
```

On Linux we can use this instead of the shell command above.

```
system("cat boxtest/*.R > boxtest.R")
```

This will also work on Windows if [Rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) is installed and the usr\bin subdirectory is on the current Windows PATH.

**2)** Alternately do it all in R:

```
writeLines(unlist(Map(readLines, Sys.glob("boxtest/*.R")), "boxtest.R")
box::use(./boxtest[...]) # or remove [...] to not export objects
```

**3)** This also seems to work althoug hit uses a function that is not exported from box and gives a few warnings but it is short and is entirely in R:

```
Map(box:::box_source, Sys.glob("boxtest/*.R"))
```

or forget about box and just use source directly:

```
Map(source, Sys.glob("boxtest/*.R"))
```